# Tooltip doesn't disappear on mouseout

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, tooltip

I'm trying to add a tooltip to a rect. It does pop up on mouse pointer hover over a bar but it doesn't want to disappear on mouseout event. I've also tried to use  div.style("display", "none"), but it doesn't work either. For some reason it doesn't want to trigger mouseover event again after mouseout. It just keep displaying a tooltip.

http://bl.ocks.org/edkiljak/dc85bf51a27122380c68909cdd09d388

```
div.tooltip {
            position: absolute;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 4px;
            font-family: Lato, arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            background: #eee;
            border-radius: 2px;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            pointer-events: none;
        }



var div = d3.select("body")
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .style("opacity", 0);

var bars = barGroup.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return heightScale(d.Vendor);
            })
            .attr("width", function (d) {
                return widthScale(+d.Share2016)
            })
            .attr("height", heightScale.bandwidth() / 1.1)
            .style("fill", function (d, i) {
                return color(i);
            })
            .on("mouseover",function (d){

                div.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                div
                    .style("opacity", .9)
                    .html("Vendor: " + "<strong>" + d.Vendor + "</strong>" + "<br>" + "Market share in 2016: " + d.Share2016 + "%")
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");


                d3.select(this)
                    .style("fill", "#93ceff")



            })
            .on("mouseout", function(){
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(50)
                    .style("fill", function(d,i){
                        return color(i);
                    })

                d3.select(div).remove()

            })
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd follow the example here. http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579 - You should use `d3.tip()` - in this example it looks like you just append the html directly to the svg, which makes it harder to then re-select it and remove it. `d3.tip()` will make your life easier.

Comment: This might work .style("visibility", "hidden"); instead of .remove()

Comment: @ShaneG it does disappear but doesn't show again, so have to reload the page

Comment: on mouseover can you do .style("visibility", "visible");

Comment: I got tooltips to clear here on line 558 https://github.com/shanegibney/RaceChart/blob/master/index.html

Comment: @ShaneG It works! Thank you and much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
d3.select(div).remove()
```

As `div` is itself a selection, you're selecting a selection, and that makes little sense.

Instead of that, just use `div` in the `mouseout`:

```
div.remove()
```

Or, even better, just set its opacity to zero:

```
div.style("opacity", 0)
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks with just that change: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/13ce2445b248fb9e44dcd33cfc3dff36/dff0c60423927960cab8aaf9e613c2c3ae205808/